# How can I enter data in the database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, localhost, laravel-artisan

I have been trying to save data in the db, but this error keeps coming:

```
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into `stores` (`name`, `description`) values (El café de mi esquina , Es lindo))
```

this is the code on the controller:

```
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */



     public function store()
        {
          $nuevoLocal= new Store();


          $nuevoLocal->name="El café de mi esquina ";
          $nuevoLocal->description="Es lindo";

$nuevoLocal-> save();

 }
```

web:

```
 Route::get('/agregarNegocio', "storeController@store");
```

model:

namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class store extends Model
{
    public $guarded =[];
    public $timestamps=false;

}
```

env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=cafe

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=root
```

The db name is cafe, and it has one table stores that has ID(primary key), name and description

If a put  var_dump($nuevoLocal); exit; just before the save() this is what i get:

```
object(App\store)#158 (25) { ["guarded"]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(false) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(23) "El café de mi esquina " ["description"]=> string(8) "Es lindo" } ["original":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["events":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: the error is a `Connection refused` so it's either one of the config to your database mostly `DB_HOST`, but it can also be `DB_PORT`.
Try `DB_HOST=localhost`

Comment: Did you correctly configure your .env file. When you are connecting to your database, do you use `Username = root` & `Password = root`

Comment: tried modifyng DB_HOST=localhost but it doesn't work ):

Comment: make sure your mysql is running.
it seems like mysql is off

Comment: mysql is running!

Answer (score 0):

Try chancing `DB_CONNECTION` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`. Apparently there are some issues with using `127.0.0.1` with Laravel.

Comment: Tried it but no results ):

Comment: Are you using the homestead vagrant box for development? Are you certain that ```root```/```root``` is the correct user info?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and turned out the Port was not standard. Try this from the SQL server

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', 'any', NULL, NULL, N'asc' 
GO
```